# oem-bt-ar-9462-dkms error in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, wireless, bluetooth

I am new to Ubuntu and I was recently prompted to install new updates and this error keeps popping up. Is there any way that I could resolve this? I am not sure what to do here and any help would be appreciated.

How do I install OEM DKMS bluetooth driver?

```
dkms status
alsa-hda, 0.201210081115~precise1annan4, 3.2.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed
ar9462, 1.2, 3.2.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed
asus-wmi, 1.14, 3.2.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed
compat-wireless-3.4-rc3-1-alx-dkms, 1, 3.2.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed
i915, 0.1, 3.2.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed
wireless-bcm43142-dkms, 6.20.55.19~bdcom0602.0400.1000.0400, 3.2.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed
```

**lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:570c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 13d3:3393 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**uname -a**

```
Linux username-X201EP 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Add the result of `dkms staus` to your question.  The bluetooth drivers are included in the Ubuntu kernel.  Also include the result of `lsusb` and `uname -a`

Comment: I have added these details to the question

Answer (score 0):

The ar9462 dkms package isn't needed with your kernel so it can be removed

```
sudo dkms remove ar9462/1.51 --all
```

You also need firmware for the bluetooth to work

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

Reboot

Are you using Ubuntu 14.04 as your current kernel would suggest, or 12.04 as that version used the kernel that is mentioned in the results of `dkms status`